# Пробую написать игру `Отгадай слово по буквам`, но третья итерация автоматически начинается с последней нажатой кнопки с буквой

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from random import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Viseliza import *
from Dialog import *


words_list ['Указатель\n', 'Радуга\n', 'Мармелад\n']
 
def display_hugman(ost): #Картнки состояния человечка

    if ost == 9:
        root_Vis.label_1.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 8:
        root_Vis.label_2.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 7:
        root_Vis.label_3.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 6:
        root_Vis.label_4.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 5:
        root_Vis.label_5.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 4:
        root_Vis.label_6.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 3:
        root_Vis.label_7.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 2:
        root_Vis.label_8.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 1:
        root_Vis.label_9.setVisible(True)
    if ost == 0:
        root_Vis.label_10.setVisible(True)

def play(word): #Функция с кнопками
    
    root_Vis.pushButtonA.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('А', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_B.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Б', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_V.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('В', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_G.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Г', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_D.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Д', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_E.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Е', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_GZ.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ж', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_Z.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('З', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_I.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('И', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_I2.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Й', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_K.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('К', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_L.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Л', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_M.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('М', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_N.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Н', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_O.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('О', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_P.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('П', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_R.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Р', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_S.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('С', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_T.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Т', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_U.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('У', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_F.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ф', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_H.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Х', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_Z_2.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ц', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_Ch.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ч', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_SCH.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ш', word))
    root_Vis.pushButtonSCH2.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Щ', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_B2.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ъ', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_B1.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ы', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_B3.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ь', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_E3.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Э', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_Yu.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Ю', word))
    root_Vis.pushButton_Ya.clicked.connect(lambda: press_sym('Я', word))
    print(word, 'play')

def press_sym(sym, word): #Если нажатая буква в слове

    global res
    global counter
    global alf_uge

    if sym in word:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if sym == word[i]:
                word[i] = '-'
                res[i] = sym
                root_Vis.label_slovo.setText(''.join(res))
                if not sym in alf_uge:
                    alf_uge.append(sym)
                    alf_uge.sort()
                root_Vis.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(alf_uge))

        if word == ['-']*len(word):
            print('ok')
            alf_uge.clear
            root_Vis.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(alf_uge))
            Vopros()
    
    else:
        if word != ['-']*len(word):
            if not sym in alf_uge:
                alf_uge.append(sym)
                alf_uge.sort()
                root_Vis.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(alf_uge))
                counter -= 1
                root_Vis.label_ost.setText(str(counter))
                display_hugman(counter)
                print('no')

    if counter == 0:
        alf_uge.clear
        root_Vis.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(alf_uge))
        Vopros()

    

def Vopros(): #Диалоговое окно играть ли еще

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    root_dialog = Ui_Dialog()
    root_dialog.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()

    root_dialog.pushButton_Yes.clicked.connect(snova)
    root_dialog.pushButton_No.clicked.connect(app.closeAllWindows)
    root_dialog.pushButton_Yes.clicked.connect(Dialog.close)
    root_dialog.pushButton_No.clicked.connect(Dialog.close)
    Dialog.exec_()

def get_word(): #Генерация слова из списка word_list 

    root_Vis.pushButton.setVisible(False)
    global word
    word = choice(words_list)
    word = word.upper()
    word = word.strip()
    word = list(word) 
    for _ in range(len(word)):
        if 'Ё' in word:
            ind = word.find('Ё')
            word = word[:ind] + 'Е' + word[ind:]
    global res
    res = ['_']*len(word)
    root_Vis.label_slovo.setText(''.join(res))
    root_Vis.label_ost.setText('10')
    print(word)
    print(res, 'res')
    play(word)

def snova(): #Обнуление и запуск игры

    skrit()
    global counter
    global alf_uge
    counter = 10
    alf_uge = []
    root_Vis.label_alf_uge.setText(' '. join(alf_uge))
    get_word()

def skrit(): #Скрыть картинки
        root_Vis.label_10.setVisible(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Viseliza = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    root_Vis = Ui_Viseliza()
    root_Vis.setupUi(Viseliza)
    snova()

    Viseliza.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Dialog.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 203)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_snova = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_snova.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 401, 261))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_snova.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_snova.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type A")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label_snova.setFont(font)
        self.label_snova.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_snova.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_snova.setObjectName("label_snova")
        self.pushButton_Yes = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 140, 85, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);")
        self.pushButton_Yes.setObjectName("pushButton_Yes")
        self.pushButton_No = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_No.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 85, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_No.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_No.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);")
        self.pushButton_No.setObjectName("pushButton_No")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Виселица"))
        self.label_snova.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Попробовать снова?"))
        self.pushButton_Yes.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ДА!"))
        self.pushButton_No.setText(_translate("Dialog", "НЕТ"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Viseliza.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Viseliza(object):
    def setupUi(self, Viseliza):
        Viseliza.setObjectName("Viseliza")
        Viseliza.resize(1091, 814)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Viseliza)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 130, 400, 600))
        self.label_1.setText("")
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 501, 91))
        self.label_name.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_name.setObjectName("label_name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 130, 400, 600))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_6.setText("")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_slovo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_slovo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 220, 571, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.label_slovo.setFont(font)
        self.label_slovo.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_slovo.setText("")
        self.label_slovo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_slovo.setObjectName("label_slovo")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 640, 131, 141))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 310, 451, 301))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_B3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B3.setObjectName("pushButton_B3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B3, 5, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B2.setObjectName("pushButton_B2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B2, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B1.setObjectName("pushButton_B1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B1, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_SCH = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_SCH.setObjectName("pushButton_SCH")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_SCH, 4, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B.setObjectName("pushButton_B")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_V = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_V.setObjectName("pushButton_V")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_V, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonA = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButtonA.setObjectName("pushButtonA")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonA, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_GZ = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_GZ.setObjectName("pushButton_GZ")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_GZ, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_E = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_E.setObjectName("pushButton_E")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_E, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Z = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Z.setObjectName("pushButton_Z")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Z, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_L = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_L.setObjectName("pushButton_L")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_L, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_K = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_K.setObjectName("pushButton_K")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_K, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_S = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_S.setObjectName("pushButton_S")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_S, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_M = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_M.setObjectName("pushButton_M")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_M, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_N = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_N.setObjectName("pushButton_N")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_N, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_O = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_O.setObjectName("pushButton_O")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_O, 2, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_R = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_R.setObjectName("pushButton_R")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_R, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_P = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_P.setObjectName("pushButton_P")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_P, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_T = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_T.setObjectName("pushButton_T")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_T, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_F = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_F.setObjectName("pushButton_F")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_F, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_U = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_U.setObjectName("pushButton_U")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_U, 3, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_H = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_H.setObjectName("pushButton_H")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_H, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonSCH2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButtonSCH2.setObjectName("pushButtonSCH2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonSCH2, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Z_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Z_2.setObjectName("pushButton_Z_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Z_2, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Ch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Ch.setObjectName("pushButton_Ch")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Ch, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_E3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_E3.setObjectName("pushButton_E3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_E3, 5, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Yu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Yu.setObjectName("pushButton_Yu")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Yu, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Ya = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Ya.setObjectName("pushButton_Ya")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Ya, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_D = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_D.setObjectName("pushButton_D")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_D, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_I = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_I.setObjectName("pushButton_I")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_I, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_G = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_G.setObjectName("pushButton_G")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_G, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_I2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_I2.setObjectName("pushButton_I2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_I2, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 140, 251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 740, 321, 41))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.label_ost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_ost.setObjectName("label_ost")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_ost)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 120, 671, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(72)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_alf_uge = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_alf_uge.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 640, 341, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type A")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_alf_uge.setFont(font)
        self.label_alf_uge.setText("")
        self.label_alf_uge.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_alf_uge.setObjectName("label_alf_uge")
        Viseliza.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Viseliza)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Viseliza.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Viseliza)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Viseliza)

    def retranslateUi(self, Viseliza):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Viseliza.setWindowTitle(_translate("Viseliza", "Виселица"))
        self.label_name.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Виселица"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Вы уже пробовали:"))
        self.pushButton_B3.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ь"))
        self.pushButton_B2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ъ"))
        self.pushButton_B1.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ы"))
        self.pushButton_SCH.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ш"))
        self.pushButton_B.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Б"))
        self.pushButton_V.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "В"))
        self.pushButtonA.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "А"))
        self.pushButton_GZ.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ж"))
        self.pushButton_E.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Е"))
        self.pushButton_Z.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "З"))
        self.pushButton_L.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Л"))
        self.pushButton_K.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "К"))
        self.pushButton_S.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "С"))
        self.pushButton_M.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "М"))
        self.pushButton_N.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Н"))
        self.pushButton_O.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "О"))
        self.pushButton_R.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Р"))
        self.pushButton_P.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "П"))
        self.pushButton_T.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Т"))
        self.pushButton_F.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ф"))
        self.pushButton_U.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "У"))
        self.pushButton_H.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Х"))
        self.pushButtonSCH2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Щ"))
        self.pushButton_Z_2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ц"))
        self.pushButton_Ch.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ч"))
        self.pushButton_E3.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Э"))
        self.pushButton_Yu.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ю"))
        self.pushButton_Ya.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Я"))
        self.pushButton_D.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Д"))
        self.pushButton_I.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "И"))
        self.pushButton_G.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Г"))
        self.pushButton_I2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Й"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Сгенерировать слово"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Осталось попыток:"))
        self.label_ost.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Вы проиграли!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Viseliza = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Viseliza()
    ui.setupUi(Viseliza)
    Viseliza.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Юлия, ваш вопрос должен сопровождать  [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Опубликуйте модули `Viseliza.py` и `Dialog.py` , а также приведите пример значения переменной `words_list`.

Comment: Если изучаете всего неделю, то рановато ещё делать приложения с интерфейсом. Сделайте для начала "виселицу" в консольном варианте.

Comment: С консольным вариантом проблем нет. Интересно попробовать шагнуть дальше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то неплохо. Я правда не совсем понял какая у вас проблема возникает и при каких действиях, sorry.
Я немного изменил расположение виджетов, т.к. у меня экран маленький и не все видать.

А также:

Не рекомендуется злоупотреблять глобальными переменными, 
как указано в разделе [**Почему глобальные переменные - зло?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Учим [**Object-Oriented Programming**](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) без него никак.

```
import sys
from random import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from Viseliza import *
class Ui_Viseliza(object):
    def setupUi(self, Viseliza):
        Viseliza.setObjectName("Viseliza")
        Viseliza.resize(1091, 714)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Viseliza)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 400, 600))
        self.label_1.setText("1")
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818;")
        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 501, 91))
        self.label_name.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_name.setObjectName("label_name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 400, 600))
        self.label_2.setText("2")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #62DD68;")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 400, 600))
        self.label_3.setText("3")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #78D398;")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 400, 600))
        self.label_4.setText("4")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: #AAD398;")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 400, 600))
        self.label_5.setText("5")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: #78D3AA;")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 400, 600))
        self.label_6.setText("6")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: #787798;")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 130, 400, 600))
        self.label_7.setText("7")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7BB748;")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 400, 600))
        self.label_8.setText("8")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: #787798;")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 150, 400, 600))
        self.label_9.setText("9")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FAFE98;")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 160, 400, 600))
        self.label_10.setText("0")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F35570;")
        self.label_slovo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_slovo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 220, 571, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift Light")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.label_slovo.setFont(font)
        self.label_slovo.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_slovo.setText("")
        self.label_slovo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_slovo.setObjectName("label_slovo")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(760, 620, 131, 141))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 310, 451, 301))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_B3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B3.setObjectName("pushButton_B3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B3, 5, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B2.setObjectName("pushButton_B2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B2, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B1.setObjectName("pushButton_B1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B1, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_SCH = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_SCH.setObjectName("pushButton_SCH")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_SCH, 4, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_B.setObjectName("pushButton_B")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_B, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_V = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_V.setObjectName("pushButton_V")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_V, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonA = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButtonA.setObjectName("pushButtonA")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonA, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_GZ = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_GZ.setObjectName("pushButton_GZ")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_GZ, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_E = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_E.setObjectName("pushButton_E")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_E, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Z = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Z.setObjectName("pushButton_Z")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Z, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_L = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_L.setObjectName("pushButton_L")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_L, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_K = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_K.setObjectName("pushButton_K")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_K, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_S = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_S.setObjectName("pushButton_S")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_S, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_M = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_M.setObjectName("pushButton_M")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_M, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_N = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_N.setObjectName("pushButton_N")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_N, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_O = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_O.setObjectName("pushButton_O")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_O, 2, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_R = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_R.setObjectName("pushButton_R")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_R, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_P = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_P.setObjectName("pushButton_P")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_P, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_T = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_T.setObjectName("pushButton_T")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_T, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_F = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_F.setObjectName("pushButton_F")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_F, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_U = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_U.setObjectName("pushButton_U")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_U, 3, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_H = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_H.setObjectName("pushButton_H")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_H, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonSCH2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButtonSCH2.setObjectName("pushButtonSCH2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonSCH2, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Z_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Z_2.setObjectName("pushButton_Z_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Z_2, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Ch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Ch.setObjectName("pushButton_Ch")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Ch, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_E3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_E3.setObjectName("pushButton_E3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_E3, 5, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Yu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Yu.setObjectName("pushButton_Yu")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Yu, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_Ya = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_Ya.setObjectName("pushButton_Ya")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_Ya, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_D = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_D.setObjectName("pushButton_D")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_D, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_I = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_I.setObjectName("pushButton_I")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_I, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_G = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_G.setObjectName("pushButton_G")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_G, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_I2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_I2.setObjectName("pushButton_I2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_I2, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 140, 251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
#        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 740, 321, 41))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 120, 300, 100))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_12)
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_ost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_ost.setObjectName("label_ost")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_ost)
        self.label_ost.setFont(font)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 30, 671, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(55)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_alf_uge = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_alf_uge.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 640, 341, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type A")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_alf_uge.setFont(font)
        self.label_alf_uge.setText("")
        self.label_alf_uge.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_alf_uge.setObjectName("label_alf_uge")
        Viseliza.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Viseliza)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Viseliza.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(Viseliza)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Viseliza)

    def retranslateUi(self, Viseliza):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Viseliza.setWindowTitle(_translate("Viseliza", "Виселица"))
        self.label_name.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Виселица"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Вы уже пробовали:"))
        self.pushButton_B3.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ь"))
        self.pushButton_B2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ъ"))
        self.pushButton_B1.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ы"))
        self.pushButton_SCH.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ш"))
        self.pushButton_B.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Б"))
        self.pushButton_V.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "В"))
        self.pushButtonA.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "А"))
        self.pushButton_GZ.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ж"))
        self.pushButton_E.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Е"))
        self.pushButton_Z.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "З"))
        self.pushButton_L.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Л"))
        self.pushButton_K.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "К"))
        self.pushButton_S.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "С"))
        self.pushButton_M.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "М"))
        self.pushButton_N.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Н"))
        self.pushButton_O.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "О"))
        self.pushButton_R.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Р"))
        self.pushButton_P.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "П"))
        self.pushButton_T.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Т"))
        self.pushButton_F.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ф"))
        self.pushButton_U.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "У"))
        self.pushButton_H.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Х"))
        self.pushButtonSCH2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Щ"))
        self.pushButton_Z_2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ц"))
        self.pushButton_Ch.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ч"))
        self.pushButton_E3.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Э"))
        self.pushButton_Yu.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Ю"))
        self.pushButton_Ya.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Я"))
        self.pushButton_D.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Д"))
        self.pushButton_I.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "И"))
        self.pushButton_G.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Г"))
        self.pushButton_I2.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Й"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Сгенерировать слово"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Осталось попыток:"))
        self.label_ost.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Viseliza", "Вы проиграли!"))

#from Dialog import *
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 203)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_snova = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_snova.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 401, 261))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_snova.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_snova.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type A")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label_snova.setFont(font)
        self.label_snova.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);")
        self.label_snova.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_snova.setObjectName("label_snova")
        self.pushButton_Yes = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 140, 85, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_Yes.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);")
        self.pushButton_Yes.setObjectName("pushButton_Yes")
        self.pushButton_No = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_No.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 140, 85, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_No.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_No.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);")
        self.pushButton_No.setObjectName("pushButton_No")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Виселица"))
        self.label_snova.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Попробовать снова?"))
        self.pushButton_Yes.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ДА!"))
        self.pushButton_No.setText(_translate("Dialog", "НЕТ"))


#with open('Words.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
#    words_list = file.readlines() #Список, где каждая строка - элемент списка

words_list = ['Указатель\n', 'Радуга\n', 'Мармелад\n']

class MainWindow( QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Viseliza):             # !!! +++ 
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.counter = 10            # !!! +++
        self.alf_uge = []            # !!! +++
        self.word = None             # !!! +++
        self.res = None              # !!! +++

        self.snova()
        self.play()                 # !!! +++ да
        
    def snova(self):                # Обнуление и запуск игры
        self.skrit()
#        global counter
#        global alf_uge
        self.counter = 10
        self.alf_uge = []
        self.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(self.alf_uge))

        self.get_word() 

    def skrit(self):                   # Скрыть картинки
        self.label_1.setVisible(False)
        self.label_2.setVisible(False)
        self.label_3.setVisible(False)
        self.label_4.setVisible(False)
        self.label_5.setVisible(False)
        self.label_6.setVisible(False)
        self.label_7.setVisible(False)
        self.label_8.setVisible(False)
        self.label_9.setVisible(False)
        self.label_10.setVisible(False)        
        self.label_11.setVisible(False) 

    def get_word(self):         # Генерация слова из списка word_list 
        self.pushButton.setVisible(False)
#        global word
        self.word = choice(words_list)
        self.word = self.word.upper()
        self.word = self.word.strip()
        self.word = list(self.word) 
        for _ in range(len(self.word)):
            if 'Ё' in self.word:
                ind = self.word.find('Ё')
                self.word = self.word[:ind] + 'Е' + self.word[ind:]
#        global res
        self.res = ['.']*len(self.word)
        
        self.label_slovo.setText(''.join(self.res))
        self.label_slovo.setStyleSheet("background-color: #995570;")
        
        self.label_ost.setText('10')
#        self.label_ost.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ff5570;")
        
        #print(f'word = {self.word}')
        #print(f'res  = {self.res}')
#        self.play()  нет 

    def play(self):             # Функция с кнопками -word
        self.pushButtonA.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('А'))
        self.pushButton_B.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Б'))
        self.pushButton_V.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('В'))
        self.pushButton_G.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Г'))
        self.pushButton_D.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Д'))
        self.pushButton_E.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Е'))
        self.pushButton_GZ.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ж'))
        self.pushButton_Z.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('З'))
        self.pushButton_I.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('И'))
        self.pushButton_I2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Й'))
        self.pushButton_K.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('К'))
        self.pushButton_L.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Л'))
        self.pushButton_M.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('М'))
        self.pushButton_N.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Н'))
        self.pushButton_O.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('О'))
        self.pushButton_P.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('П'))
        self.pushButton_R.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Р'))
        self.pushButton_S.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('С'))
        self.pushButton_T.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Т'))
        self.pushButton_U.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('У'))
        self.pushButton_F.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ф'))
        self.pushButton_H.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Х'))
        self.pushButton_Z_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ц'))
        self.pushButton_Ch.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ч'))
        self.pushButton_SCH.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ш'))
        self.pushButtonSCH2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Щ'))
        self.pushButton_B2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ъ'))
        self.pushButton_B1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ы'))
        self.pushButton_B3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ь'))
        self.pushButton_E3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Э'))
        self.pushButton_Yu.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Ю'))
        self.pushButton_Ya.clicked.connect(lambda: self.press_sym('Я'))
        #print(self.word, 'play --------------------------')    

    def press_sym(self, sym):        # Если нажатая буква в слове  
#        global res
#        global counter
#        global alf_uge
        if not self.counter:             # +++
            self.vopros()
            return
 
        if sym in self.word:
            for i in range(len(self.word)):
                if sym == self.word[i]:
                    self.word[i] = '-'
                    self.res[i] = sym
                    self.label_slovo.setText(''.join(self.res))
                    if not sym in self.alf_uge:
                        self.alf_uge.append(sym)
                        self.alf_uge.sort()
                    self.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(self.alf_uge))

            if self.word == ['-']*len(self.word):
                print('ok')
                self.alf_uge.clear()                                     #  () 
                self.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(self.alf_uge))

                self.counter = 0                                         # +++
                self.label_11.setText('Успех, поздавляем!')              # +++
                self.label_11.setVisible(True)                           # +++
                
                self.vopros()                                      
        
        else:
            if self.word != ['-']*len(self.word):
                if not sym in self.alf_uge:
                    self.alf_uge.append(sym)
                    self.alf_uge.sort()
                    self.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(self.alf_uge))
                    self.counter -= 1
                    self.label_ost.setText(str(self.counter))
                    
                    print('no')
                    self.display_hugman()

        if self.counter == 0:
            self.alf_uge.clear()                                          #  ()
            self.label_alf_uge.setText(' '.join(self.alf_uge))
            self.vopros()  

    def vopros(self):                           #  Диалоговое окно играть ли еще
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        root_dialog = Ui_Dialog()
        root_dialog.setupUi(self.dialog)
#         self.dialog.show()

        root_dialog.pushButton_Yes.clicked.connect(self.snova)
        root_dialog.pushButton_No.clicked.connect(app.closeAllWindows)
        root_dialog.pushButton_Yes.clicked.connect(self.dialog.close)
        root_dialog.pushButton_No.clicked.connect(self.dialog.close)
        self.dialog.exec_()            

    def display_hugman(self):                      # Картнки состояния человечка
        print(f'ost = {self.counter}') #
        if self.counter == 9:
            self.label_1.setVisible(True)
# elif  vvvv <------------------------------------------------------------------
        elif self.counter == 8:
            self.label_2.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 7:
            self.label_3.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 6:
            self.label_4.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 5:
            self.label_5.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 4:
            self.label_6.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 3:
            self.label_7.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 2:
            self.label_8.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 1:
            self.label_9.setVisible(True)
        elif self.counter == 0:
            self.label_10.setVisible(True)
            self.label_11.setText("Вы проиграли!")                # +++
            self.label_11.setVisible(True)                        # +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
            color: #000833;
            font-size: 21px;
        }

    """)
    
#    Viseliza = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    root_Vis = Ui_Viseliza()
#    root_Vis.setupUi(Viseliza)
#    snova()
    w = MainWindow()                                             # !!! +++
    w.show()                                                     # !!! +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема возникала такая, что при 3-ей попытке начать игру заново, последняя буква из второй попытки, засчитывалась сама сразу же в третью. Большое спасибо, теперь всё работает, буду разбираться в чём была ошибка)

Comment: @Юлия пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour